# Listing customization

Tags: listings, code

I'm really new to latex and I would like to insert code snippet to look like this:

[image]

But I really don't know where to start. I just managed  to set the background color, but I can't figure out how to set a default color to the text (when no specific programming language is selected) and how to make rounded corners to the background (if it is possible). Also I'd like to understand how to set up margin/padding and if it possible for the background to extend just as much as the length of the content.

Can anybody help me achieving this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would really help us to help you if you could post an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I recommend checking out the [minted](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ctan+minted) and [listings](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!ctan+listings) packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) package, you can use it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{listing-bg}{RGB}{1 44 55}
\definecolor{listing-text}{RGB}{147 161 161}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcblisting}{listing only,colback=listing-bg,hbox,colframe=white,listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{listing-text}}}
git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet
    \end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

The options are:

- `listing only` If this is not used, the result of the code, evaluated as `latex` code, is also shown in the bottom part of the box
- `colback=listing-bg` This sets the background color of the box
- `hbox` This option shrinks the box to its horizontal contents
- `colframe=white` To hide the frame
- `listing options={<options>}` Passes its options on to the [`listings`](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package

  - `language={}` Sets the language to nothing
  - `basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{listing-text}` Sets the font for basic text to the specified color and to the typewriter family font. With `language={}` this means all text will be this font.

The result is:

[image]

**Edit**
I forgot one of the topics you mentioned: padding. This can be adjusted on all sides by the `boxsep` key, which defaults to `1mm` and which also accepts negative values. Otherwise, you can change it separately with the `right`, `left`, `top`, and `bottom` keys. See subsection 4.7.4 on page 39 of the [manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) for these options.

**Edit 2**
Of course it is possible to make a new environment to re-use these settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % Only used for dummy text

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{listing-bg}{RGB}{1 44 55}
\definecolor{listing-text}{RGB}{147 161 161}

\newtcblisting{myCommandLineBox}{listing only,colback=listing-bg,hbox,colframe=white,bottom=0mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=-2pt,listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{listing-text}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myCommandLineBox}
sudo apt-get update
    \end{myCommandLineBox}
    \lipsum[1] % Dummy text
    \begin{myCommandLineBox}
git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet
    \end{myCommandLineBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 3**
To add some indentation to the boxes, you can use the `left skip` key. I used `\parindent` to align them with indented paragraphs, but you can use any length (also negative).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % Only used for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe} % To show the page boundaries

\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{listing-bg}{RGB}{1 44 55}
\definecolor{listing-text}{RGB}{147 161 161}

\newtcblisting{myCommandLineBox}{
    listing only,
    colback=listing-bg,
    hbox,
    colframe=white,
    left skip=\parindent,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    top=-2pt,
    listing options={
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{listing-text}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{myCommandLineBox}
sudo apt-get update
    \end{myCommandLineBox}
    \lipsum[1] % Dummy text
    \begin{myCommandLineBox}
git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet
    \end{myCommandLineBox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect for what I'm looking for! Is there away to create a fixed behaviour for this in order to not have to repeat all that parameters for each code snippet?

Comment: @Mdp11 Sure! See my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! One last thing (which is not really necessary), how could I give it some margin to the left to the whole block? In all my tries I just end up having some blank space (with the colored background) and then the code snippet. How can I move the whole block instead?

Comment: Again, sure! See edit number 3

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I encountered another problem. When the line of code is too long, it will just overflow out of the boundaries of the box. I tried using breakable, but it does not work. With the \listing package I saw it's possible to make it auto break the line when it reaches the limit and also to add an arrow to emphatize the line break. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: Well, you will have to choose between the `hbox` option, or adding `breaklines` to the `listing options`. The one does not work well with the other. There might be a solution with the [`varwidth`](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth/varwidth-doc.pdf) package, but I cannot help you with that unfortunately. You could always ask a new question and refer back to this one. Please do include the code you already have as an MWE when you ask a new question.